# Why Couchbase Serever does not work on windows 10?

Tags: windows, couchbase

I installed **Couchbase Serever** on my windows 10, It worked fine for first time and I entered the admin panel through **127.0.0.1:8091** url,

but after rebooting my system It is not working now and when I run Couchbase server it opens 127.0.0.1:8091 url but the url just shows the following JSON object in the browser:

```
{"ADMIN":true,"couchdb":"Welcome","vendor":{"name":"Couchbase Sync Gateway","version":1.5},"version":"Couchbase Sync Gateway/1.5.1(4;cb9522c)"}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response string you've quoted is from Couchbase Sync Gateway.

It looks like you configured Sync Gateway to respond on port 8091.  This is not the default port, so you must be specifying it in a configuration file somewhere.

8091 is the default admin web console port for Couchbase Server.  If Sync Gateway is taking that port first, I expect Couchbase Server will fail to start.